# numpy\arrayobject.h not find by MinGW g++ while compiling SWIG python wrapper in Windows

Tags: c++, python, numpy, mingw, swig

On my debian distribution, I managed to build a python module in C++ using SWIG. The module `Amod` can be imported succesfully in more complex python code and work fine. Here the compilation used on Linux :

```
swig -c++ -python test5.i
g++ -fPIC -c test5.cpp
g++ -fPIC -c test5_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7
g++ -shared test5.o test5_wrap.o -o _Amod.so
```

But now I want recomplie it on Windows, and I am not sure of what I am doing.

I installed numpy 1.7.0. and MinGW with g++, and I added path for swig in the "PATH" environment variable, as explained in the SWIG doc. I added also path to my Python 2.7.5 installation and to Python.h.

I open the windows terminal and type :

```
swig -c++ -Wall -python test5.i
g++ -c -Wall test5.cpp
```

It compiles without problems. then

```
g++ -c test5_wrap.cxx
```

`fatal error: Python.h: no such file or directory`. I don't get it, the path to Python.h isn't in the PATH variable !? so I type

```
g++ -c test5_wrap.cxx -I C:\Python27\include
```

`fatal error: numpy\arrayobject.h: no such file or directory`. I don't get it either, this header exists in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\`. Then I tried

```
g++ -c test5_wrap.cxx -I C:\Python27\include C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\
```

same error and so I tried :

```
g++ -c test5_wrap.cxx -I C:\Python27\include C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h
```

give a huge pile of errors beginning with the same `fatal error: numpy\arrayobject.h: no such file or directory`.

How solve that ? Is MinGW + SWIG + g++ the right direction for my python module compilation ?

Thanks a lot.

F.M

Edit : Meanwhile I tried also to compile this python module with distutils with this setup.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Oct 23 17:01:51 2013

@author: Florian
"""
from distutils.core import setup, Extension


Amod = Extension('_Amod',
                           sources=['test5_wrap.cxx', 'test5.cpp'],
                           )

setup (name = 'Amod',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "FM",
       description = """Come on""",
       ext_modules = [Amod],
       py_modules = ["Amod"],
       )
```

And compiling with :

```
python setup.py build_ext --compiler=mingw32 --swig-opts="-c++ -I :C/Python27/include -I :C/Python27/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/"
```

And still this dammit error :

```
running build_ext
building '_Amod' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c test5_wrap.cxx -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Rel
ease\test5_wrap.o
test5_wrap.cxx:3045:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
 #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
```

I googled the error  `undefined reference to _imp__Py...` that I got with my first try, but people talk about missing linked library, I don't see which library I should link and why. It's a bit over my skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to `-I C:\Python27\include -I C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include`. Those paths are needed so gcc knows where to search for the include headers.

In a *nix environment, there are likely environment variables and other implicit search paths gcc looks in when looking for include headers and that's probably why it compiles successfully . On windows mingw, however, you'll have to specify those paths explicitly so it looks in the right place.

Comment: Ok, It compiles. I get a Warning : `: Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it
#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
                             #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")`

Comment: @fmollica Not sure what that's about. Maybe the bindings are using some deprecated functions that's going to be phased out in a future version? Probably want to google and check the numpy doc or the repo's commit log. You should find something about the warning

Comment: Ok, It compiles, I believed I could stack path after -I.... I get a Warning : `: Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it
#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
                             #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")` 


When I finish by the last step : 

`g++ -shared test5.o test5_wrap.o -o _Amod.pyd`

It gives me plenty of error 
` undefined reference to `_imp__Py...`

like if some library where missing

Comment: @fmollica Yeah, it's the same story. Make sure you provide `-L library/path` + either the import library, .dll or .so module to the linker so it can find those unresolved functions. On a windows environment, a default python install will have import libraries under python*/libs with `*.lib` extension.

Comment: In short, you can either pass `pythonxx.dll` to the linker or `*/libs/pythonxx.lib` where *xx* is the python version you are using.

Comment: By the way, thank you for your help :) .Halas I am not done. What do you call the "linker" ? I tried `g++ -shared -L C:\Python27\libs\ test5.o test5_wrap.o -o _Amod.pyd` which give the same error `undefined reference to _imp__Py` and `g++ -shared -l C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib test5.o test5_wrap.o -o _Amod.pyd` and it tells me `/mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Python27\libs\python27.lib` whereas it exists in this place ! Strange

Comment: Try `g++ -shared test5.o test5_wrap.o -o _Amod.pyd -L C:\Python27\libs -lpython27`. You can also pass it in with fully qualified path: `g++ -shared test5.o test5_wrap.o -o _Amod.pyd C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib`.

Comment: And two days of blood and tears come to an end. The right form was indeed `g++ -Wall -shared -I C:\Python27\include -I C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\ test5.o test5_wrap.o -o _Amod.pyd -L C:/Python27/libs/ -lpython27`. Thank you again. It need to be noted too that one of the bug I get in this SWIG process was the bad encoding of my .i files, they need to be carefully encode in utf-8. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in cygwin while compiling a c++ code.  Solution was to install python2-devel and python2-numpy, and then use the command "python -m site" in order to see the python installation directories.  Use the following find command to locate the header file: find /usr/lib/python2.7 -name "*.h".  The header files are under directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include.  Include this path with the following include option to the g++ command: -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include.