# arrayobject.h not found while compiling swig output

Tags: python, c++, swig

I found many similar questions people had problem with this file. I know where the header file is and I address the g++ with `-I`, as people usually answered to previous questions. I did all of them, but they did not worked.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522363/compiling-swig-wrapper-for-python-in-windows),[2](https://github.com/andersbll/cudarray/issues/25)

```
sum_array_wrap.cpp:3124:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
g++: error: sum_array_wrap.o: No such file or directory
```

**build.sh**

```
swig -python -c++ -o sum_array_wrap.cpp sum_array.i
g++ -c sum_array.cpp -o sum_array.o -fpic -std=c++0x
g++ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ -c sum_array_wrap.cpp -o sum_array.o -fpic -std=c++0x
g++ sum_array_wrap.o sum_array.o -o _sum_array.so -shared -Wl,-soname,_sum_array
```

Do you have a solution?
[codes.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvq096ac16pevtq/1.zip?dl=0)

```
/* File sum_array.cpp */

/* Define function implementation */
double sum_array(double* input_array, int length) {

  /* Initialize sum */
  double sum = 0.;

  /* Compute sum of array elements */
  for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
    sum += input_array[i];

  return sum;
}

//*******************************************************//

/* File sum_array.h */

/* Define function prototype to take in a NumPy array */
double sum_array(double* input_array, int length);

//*******************************************************//
/* File sum_array.i */
%module sum_array

%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  #include "sum_array.h"
%}

/* Include the NumPy typemaps library */
%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
  import_array();
%}

/* Typemap for the sum_list(double* input_list, int length) C/C++ routine */
%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* input_array, int length)};
/*the first tuple is a pair of the typemap (array type and dimension) 
while the second is the function signature to match using that typemap.*/

%include "sum_array.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed `-I /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy`, but SWIG is expecting you to stop at "include" since it's looking for `numpy/arrayobject.h`.